# Data Not Displaying When Converting Visualforce Page to LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, html

I've been following a tutorial by this website: http://santanuboral.blogspot.com/2017/02/display-records-with-rowspan-in.html as it has been the exact requirement I am looking for.

[image]

But I really want to practice incorporating latest technology from Salesforce, which is Lightning Web Components (LWC). So I've been trying to convert it to LWC. After multiple research, I have been able to create something. But upon deploying it on my devhub org and displaying it through a lightning tab, only the header part are displayed. There are no data on the body part.

Here's what I achieved so far:

**contactLWC.html**

```
<template>

    <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered ">
     <thead>
      <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
       <th class="" scope="col">
        <div class="slds-truncate" title="contactModule">Module</div>
       </th>
       <th class="" scope="col">
        <div class="slds-truncate" title="contactName">Name</div>
       </th>
       <th class="" scope="col">
        <div class="slds-truncate" title="contactEmail">Email</div>
       </th>
       <th class="" scope="col">
        <div class="slds-truncate" title="contactPhone">Phone</div>
       </th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <template if:true={mapData}>
       <template for:each={mapData} for:item="keyValue">
        <tr key={keyValue.key} class="slds-hint-parent">
            <th scope="col">
                <div>{keyValue.key}</div>
            </th>
            <template for:each={keyValue.value} for:item="value">
                <div key={value.Name}>
                    {value.Name}
                </div> 
                <div key={value.Email}>
                    {value.Email}
                </div> 
                <div key={value.Phone}>
                    {value.Phone}
                </div> 
            </template>
        </tr>      
       </template>
      </template>
     </tbody>
    </table>
</template>
```

**contactLWC.js**

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';

import getDataFromApex from '@salesforce/apex/ContactController.getData';

export default class contactLWC extends LightningElement {

    @track mapData = [];

    @wire(getDataFromApex) 
    wiredcontactdata({ data, error }) {
        if (data) {
            for(let key in data) {

                if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) { 
                    this.mapData.push({key: key, value: data[key]});
                }
            }
        } else if (error) {
            window.console.log(error);
        }
    }

}
```

**ContactController.cls**

```
public class ContactController{

    public ContactController()
    {
    }

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)

    public static List<String> getData()
    {

     Map<String, List<ContactWrapper>> mapModule = new Map<String, List<ContactWrapper>>();
     Map<String, Integer> moduleCountMap = new Map<String, Integer>();
     List<String> moduleList = new List<String>();

     List<Contact> contactList = [SELECT Name, Email, Phone, Module__c 
            FROM Contact 
            WHERE Module__c != null 
            ORDER BY Module__c];

     for(Contact contObj:contactList)
     {
      List<ContactWrapper> conWrapperList = new List<ContactWrapper>();

      if(mapModule.containsKey(contObj.Module__c))
      {

       conWrapperList = mapModule.get(contObj.Module__c);


       conWrapperList.add(new ContactWrapper(contObj));

       mapModule.put(contObj.Module__c, conWrapperList);


       moduleCountMap.put(contObj.Module__c, conWrapperList.size());
      }
      else
      {

       conWrapperList.add(new ContactWrapper(contObj));
       mapModule.put(contObj.Module__c, conWrapperList);


       moduleCountMap.put(contObj.Module__c, conWrapperList.size());
      }
     }


     moduleList = new List<String>(mapModule.keySet()); 

     return moduleList;

    }

    public Class ContactWrapper {

     public ContactWrapper(Contact contObj)
     {
      this.Name = contObj.Name;
      this.Email = contObj.Email;
      this.Phone = contObj.Phone;
      this.Module = contObj.Module__c;
     }

     public String Name {get;set;}
     public String Email {get;set;}
     public String Phone {get;set;}
     public String Module {get;set;}
    }


   }
```

Would really appreciate anyone's help. Hope someone could help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import the apex method in lwc.

```
import getDataFromApex from '@salesforce/apex/ContactController.getData';
```

Change your method signature to return the map data. And change the return statement as well, like below.

Also, you need to add the auraEnabled to all the wrapper class members with getter/setters.

so the final code may look like.

```
public class ContactController {

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Map<String, List<ContactWrapper>> getData() {
        Map<String, List<ContactWrapper>> mapModule = new Map<String, List<ContactWrapper>>();
        Map<String, Integer> moduleCountMap = new Map<String, Integer>();
        //List<String> moduleList = new List<String>();

        List<Contact> contactList = [
            SELECT Name, Email, Phone, Module__c
            FROM Contact
            WHERE Module__c != null
            ORDER BY Module__c
        ];

        for (Contact contObj : contactList) {
            List<ContactWrapper> conWrapperList = new List<ContactWrapper>();

            if (mapModule.containsKey(contObj.Module__c)) {
                conWrapperList = mapModule.get(contObj.Module__c);

                conWrapperList.add(new ContactWrapper(contObj));

                mapModule.put(contObj.Module__c, conWrapperList);

                moduleCountMap.put(contObj.Module__c, conWrapperList.size());
            } else {
                conWrapperList.add(new ContactWrapper(contObj));
                mapModule.put(contObj.Module__c, conWrapperList);

                moduleCountMap.put(contObj.Module__c, conWrapperList.size());
            }
        }
        return mapModule;
    }

    public class ContactWrapper {
        public ContactWrapper(Contact contObj) {
            this.Name = contObj.Name;
            this.Email = contObj.Email;
            this.Phone = contObj.Phone;
            this.Module = contObj.Module__c;
        }
        @AuraEnabled
        public String Name { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled
        public String Email { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled
        public String Phone { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled
        public String Module { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Also, you can take out the row span calculation out of the apex, and apex just have to return the data. You can calculate the row span in the JS controller itself.  I have demonstrated that on my blog post [SLDS table with Cell Merge in LWC](https://sftrailmixer.blogspot.com/2019/11/how-to-create-slds-table-with-cell.html)

Instead of the wired property try wired method so you can log the errors on the console.

```
@wire(getDataFromApex) 
wiredContactdata({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
        this.contactdata = data;
        this.error = undefined;
        console.log('data : ', JSON.stringify(data));
    } else if (error) {
        console.log('error : ', JSON.stringify(error));
        this.error = error;
        this.contactdata = undefined;
    }
}
```

Also you will need to replace `contactdata.data` with `contactdata` in your html.

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response, and also for your blog recommendation! Will check both of it then let you know the result.

Comment: I've added your recommendations regarding importing of apex method, changing method signature and return statements, as well as adding @AuraEnabled to Wrapper properties. Even removed rowspan for now. But unfortunately, there are still no records displaying. Maybe there's something wrong with my page, will still going to check on that part also.

Comment: Noticed also that data are embedded on js as samples on your blog post. Is there a way I can make use of my existing approach and call that on js file?? Is that possible?

Comment: check the apex debug logs, also instead of wired property try wire method so you can check the console logs. here is the example. I will update that in my answer

Comment: yes, that is also possible you just need to replace the hardcoded data with data queried from the apex.

Comment: @Ertyq I have updated my answer please check.

Comment: Seen it just now, thanks! Will apply necessary modifications on it.

Comment: Been checking the debug logs, so far it returned all existing 10 records. But still, records aren't displayed on the page every time I view it :(

Comment: can you add the updated HTML code in the question? are you getting any error?

Comment: I've updated html file just now, kindly view it. I just omitted the rowspan and replaced contactdata.data with just contactdata. I just refresh the page after deploying changes. No errors, but there are no records.

Comment: you need to convert the map into array. check [this](https://newstechnologystuff.com/2019/04/07/iterate-map-in-lightning-web-components-lwc/#:~:text=In%20Lightning%20we%20use%20aura,to%20give%20them%20a%20unique.) @Ertyq

Comment: Thanks for recommending another reference. Aside from the link you've shared, I also tried [this one](https://www.salesforcecodecrack.com/2019/05/how-to-iterate-map-of-list-values-in.html). Records are now displaying, but only module and name fields are showing. I even tried revising codes from both sources just to include email and phone fields , but only the headers are visible. Debug logs show their values. I updated both html and js files, can you also check?

Comment: can you please post a new question with that code?

Comment: Alright, will post another for this specific issue. Meanwhile, thank you so much for the help :))

Answer (score 3):

You need to add  `@AuraEnabled` to your Wrapper properties

```
     @AuraEnabled
     public String Name {get;set;}
     @AuraEnabled
     public String Email {get;set;}
     @AuraEnabled
     public String Phone {get;set;}
     @AuraEnabled
     public String Module {get;set;}
```

Comment: points out one problem +1.